# I want to make it either print true or false from using variables and lists

Tags: python

```
    x = 1
    y = ['1','2']
    if x/y[1] == 2:
       print ('true')
    else:
       print ('false')
```

But the variable can not be divided by a list and it gives out

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not *cast* before division: `x/int(y[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to divide a string. Changing your code to convert `y` into an `int` will fix your problem.

```
x = 1
y = ['1','2']
if x/int(y[1]) == 2:
   print ('true')
else:
   print ('false')
```